# What to do when one leopard gecko bites another?

Tags: reptiles, lizards, leopard-geckos, geckos

I'm not sure what to do I have two leopard geckos and I was just feeding them and one of them bite the others head and now theirs a small noticeable hole should I take it to the vet or whatever or will it heal naturally.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: what gender are they? and i think to give a correct answer you would need to post a picture or give a much more detailed description of the wound. My personal mantra is "when in doubt, taking them is better than not"

Answer (score 3):

It could be for the following reasons:

- You have two male geckos, which fight (check if they have a bump underneath their bottom)
- They don't have enough room
- Medical Reasons
- They are still young and panic a lot
- Playing/Restless
  -etc.

I need more information to confirm any of these.
I recommend observing them and taking them to the vet.

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the two of them into different tanks and if you need them to eventually share a tank then keep trying to introduce them in a mutual environment so there’s no territorial issues until they get used to each other and start liking each other. Then sl